# How to switch C++ array elements positions based on specified conditions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm having a little problem with getting my head around this homework task. The task says:

"Write a function called  **MoveSmallest** that moves all the minimal integer elements at the start of the array. All the remaining items must stay at their places. (the array and its size are parameters)

*Example:* the array: 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1 changes into  1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 2

```
void MoveSmallest(int A[],int n)
{
int Min;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        Min=A[i];
    }
    else if(A[i]<=Min)
    {
        Min=A[i];
    }
}
```

So far I've only figured to check which one is the smallest element of the array. I don't have any ideas what to do next.

Comment: You can use std::swap() to... eh.. swap two elements in your array. All you need is to figure out which ones you need. You can write another cycle, which compares each element with Min and swaps it with one of the leftmost elements.

Comment: You've got the first step right. You now need to figure out how to move all the elements that equal `Min` to the beginning of the array. A good way to start is to think about moving just one element to the beginning, and how you're going to shift all subsequent elements one spot down.  
@grungegurunge Swap wouldn't work here since OP mentions that the order of the remaining elements needs to be preserved

Comment: @GLC _and how you're going to shift all subsequent elements one spot down_ You mean "up"?

Comment: _"All the remaining items must stay at their places."_ I assume that this means "must stay in their original order", right? Because the first `2` in the example certainly does not stay in the same place in the array.

Comment: This would seem to be a  two line solution using `std::min_element` and `std::stable_partition`.

Comment: Yeah, it means that the order of the "not-smallest" elements in the array must remain the same. Sorry for not specifying. The "example" sums what the function has to do pretty well.

Comment: Also, I'm not allowed to use any predefined functions.

Comment: @TheM1KE25 Well, implement what stable_partition does.  That's your answer, or at least the hint to how to proceed.

Comment: I believe the assignment was given to see if you can devise a way other than the answer that you accepted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No. For this assignment, I can only the very basics of the language. Loops, if's, own functions, arrays. That's all so that's why I chose that answer.

Comment: @mcholewinski -- You seem to misunderstand. You can use C++ without any libraries and still come up with a more efficient answer. Do you think those functions use magic to do their work? No. It is just that you haven't thought out how to solve the problem more efficiently. In reality, this is not a C++ issue -- it is an issue with coming up with a better way (not in terms of code) of partitioning the items.  See my answer as to one way to do this more efficiently using extra array space.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that. I also know that there is a whole lot of better solutions than those that I come up with but as a beginner, in C++ I guess that the solution that I chose is good enough. Learning something is about becoming better at the said subject so I think that it's not a huge issue to start with less efficient ideas and gradually make them better. Nevertheless, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have found the minimum value, all there is left to do is moving things around in order to have the minimum values at the beginning of the array.

You can do this by permuting the values until you have arrived to the "left" of the array (i.e index 0).

```
void MoveSmallest(int A[],int n)
{
    int Min;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            Min=A[i];
        }
        else if(A[i]<=Min)
        {
            Min=A[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] == Min)
        {
            for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                int tmp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j-1];
                A[j-1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `std::swap` to do the permutation, instead of the temporary variable `tmp`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that that's the solution in my case because I can only use the very basics of C++.

Comment: This solution may work, but is inefficient, as it is quadratic in runrime.  100 elements means 10000 loop iterations.  There are more efficient ways to partition items, such as using divide and conquer, similar to a merge sort.

Comment: Yes, I do know these considerations. But given that this is a homework exercise, I guessed that a simple-to-write solution was the best suited for this question.

Comment: Yup. Just as @n0m1s said. I can only use the basics of the language. It doesn't have to be optimal or efficient.

Comment: @TheM1KE25 Merge sort can be implemented using "basics of the language".  The issue is that you haven't thought through a better way to do this using basics of the language.

Comment: @n0m1s -- Yes, but the goal of the beginner should, as early as possible, actually try to think of better ways to do things.  I wouldn't be surprised if this solution is given a `B` or `B-` grade and not `A` by the teacher (where the teacher is looking for better ways, noticing how inefficient the solution is).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand your point. But I do believe that a fully-understood method (as naïve and inefficient as it is) is better to learn a language than a poorly-understood copy-pasted code.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the end of the array, keep track of how many minimal elements you have encountered. Then whenever you encounter a non-minimum element, move it to the right the number of minimal elements you have encountered so far:

```
void MoveSmallest(int A[], int n)
{
    int min;

    //Find min logic

    //shift non-min elements and count min elements
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = n-1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        if (A[i] == min)
            cnt++;
        else
            A[i+cnt] = A[i];
    }

    //Add min elements
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        A[i] = min;

}
```

This will run in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

Since your posts mention "basic C++" but not mention what is "basic", here is another solution.  This is under the assumption that creating arrays for "work" purposes is considered "basic C++".

```
void MoveSmallest(int A[], int n)
{
    // get the minimum value
    int Min = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] < Min)
            Min = A[i];
    }

    // get the count of the number of minimum values
    int minCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] == Min)
            ++minCount;
    }

    if (minCount > 0)
    {
        // create a work array and fill in the first
        // minCount values with the minimum value
        int *B = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < minCount; ++i)
            B[i] = Min;

        // now fill in the rest of the work array with the values
        // in the A[] array that are not equal to Min
        int current_pos = minCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (A[i] != Min)
                B[current_pos++] = A[i];
        }

        // Now copy work array back to A array  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            A[i] = B[i];

        // get rid of work array
        delete[] B;
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a02f35bca14a4ee)

This runs in linear time `O(n)`, as opposed to quadratic time `O(n*n)`.

The disadvantage of course is that you need room for the work array, so the memory cost is linear `O(n)`.